# Is Java a dynamic programming language?

Tags: java, programming-languages, computer-science

The definition of Dynamic Programming language says "These languages are those which perform multiple general behaviours at run-time in contrary to static programming languages which do the same at compile time. It can be by addition of new code, by extending objects and definitions".

To the best of my knowledge many programming languages have encapsulation in form of packages like Java or header files like C++. So, the code that as a programmer I will write will certainly expand at compile time and would be eventually converted to assembly code and finally to machine code. So does every high level language becomes dynamic?

Comment: When you say "The definition" - which definition? Where are you getting that from? That seems a fairly badly-worded definition to me.

Comment: You are saying that compile-time expansion of your code would make it dynamic, when your defines this as a property of a static programming language?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for that little vague statement. I read this definition in one of my textbook and I found a similar statement on Wikipedia hence concluded the same. However, this concept of dynamic and static programming languages is confusing for me. It will be very helpful if you can guide with any good references for studying more on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, one can differentiate static vs dynamic programming languages by their type systems. in dynamic type system you can have the following

```
var x = 2
x = "c"
```

meaning, the type of a given variable may change during its life time. static type systems do not allow that. C# `dynamic` data type is an example of this feature.

Be careful not to confuse dynamic with inferred or weak type systems. an inferred type system will not require formal declaration of the variable, but will infer the type from the assigned value. it will not allow the variable to be re-declared with different type.

```
var x = 2  // the type of x is int
x = "C"  // compile error: incompatible types!
```

a weak type system is one that allows operations that are not compatible with the declared type of the variable. C allows pointers to be casted to any type:

```
foo(void *ptr) {
  char *str;
  strcpy(str, (char *)ptr);
  int i = &(int *)ptr + 1;
}
```

all combinations of type systems exist, sometimes in the same programming langauge: static/dynamic, implicit(inferred)/explicit, weak/strong.

Comment: Dynamic programming langiuage != dynamic type system. Most of them are both, but not all.

Comment: @user207421 If it's not on the basis of the variable's data type changes then how exactly do we differentiate between static and dynamic programming languages. could you please share any link(s) for having a little more deep dive into this concept.

Comment: The concept : **Dynamically  language** VS **Dynamically typed launguage** is not same thing!   i.e. Python is static typed ,but dynamically language

Comment: [Wiki:Most dynamic languages are also dynamically typed, but not all are.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language)